# Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime when returning trait object from trait method

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to make something like immutable Dictionary trait that can be added new items (references) into and used without affecting the previous version. Minimal example:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct SetOfValues<'a> {
    value: Vec<&'a i32>,
}

pub trait TheSetAccessor<'b> {
    fn with_additional_values(&self, new_set: Vec<&'b i32>) -> Box<dyn TheSetAccessor<'b>>;
    fn get_from_set(&self, index: usize) -> &i32;
}

impl<'a, 'b : 'a> TheSetAccessor<'b> for SetOfValues<'a> {
    fn with_additional_values(&self, new_set: Vec<&'b i32>) -> Box<dyn TheSetAccessor<'b>> {
        Box::new(SetOfValues { value: new_set } )
    }

    fn get_from_set(&self, index: usize) -> &i32 {
        self.value[index]
    }
}

fn usage() {
    let a = 0;
    let set = SetOfValues {
        value: vec![&a]
    };

    // ...

    let b = 1;
    let extended_set = set.with_additional_values(vec![&a, &b]);

    // ...

    let got_b = extended_set.get_from_set(1);
}
```

The error message is following:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/test.rs:13:18
   |
13 |         Box::new(SetOfValues { value: new_set } )
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined here...
  --> src/test.rs:11:10
   |
11 | impl<'a, 'b : 'a> TheSetAccessor<'b> for SetOfValues<'a> {
   |          ^^
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/test.rs:13:39
   |
13 |         Box::new(SetOfValues { value: new_set } )
   |                                       ^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Vec<&i32>`
              found `Vec<&'b i32>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/test.rs:13:9
   |
13 |         Box::new(SetOfValues { value: new_set } )
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Box<(dyn TheSetAccessor<'b> + 'static)>`
              found `Box<dyn TheSetAccessor<'b>>`
```

As far as I understand, the new SetOfValues should have the lifetime of the passed vector ('b), but this part

> first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'b` as defined here...

as I see, suggests that the new instance of SetOfValues has another lifetime ('static ?) that is supposed to live longer than 'b. I don't quite understand how I can restrict this lifetime. What can I do to make this code work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `dyn Trait` is actually `dyn Trait + 'static`. Thus, `dyn TheSetAccessor<'b>` is actually `dyn TheSetAccessor<'b> + 'static`, and cannot contain any non-`'static` lifetime, so it requires `'b: 'static`.

To relax this bound add a lifetime to the trait: `dyn TheSetAccessor<'b> + 'b`. Note this may not be the best solution, depending on your use case.

```rust
fn with_additional_values(&self, new_set: Vec<&'b i32>) -> Box<dyn TheSetAccessor<'b> + 'b>;
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdcbc140f0fa1ee97b7db85af7c3aa6b).